# Validating and Encrypting A Password Program in Python

Tags: python, encryption

I am having a heck of a time writing this program to validate and encrypt a password.

I started with a skeleton program and built upon it. I just really need a second pair of eyes on it and see what I am doing wrong.

The output is supposed to validate a password and then encrypt it. Thanks for your help!

```
def password_check(password):

#password should contain at least 8 characters
def length_test(password):
    if len(password) >=8:
        return true
    else:
        return false
#validating uppercase letter in password
def uppercase_test(password):
    if i.isupper(password):
        return true
    else:
        return false
#validating lowercase letters in password
def lowercase_test(password):
    if i.islower(password):
        return true
    else:
        return false
#validating number in password
def digit_test(password):
    if i.isdigit(password):
        return true
    else:
        return false
#validating special character in password
def special_character_test(password):
    if special_char(password):
        specical_char = ["$", "@", "#", "%", "*"]
        return true
    else:
        return false
def encrypt(password):
  encrypted_character = + 1
  encrypted_character = - 1
print (ord("A")) # prints the ASCII value of "A"
print(chr(66)) # print "B" based on value of ASCII code 66

def main ():
    password_check(password)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
user_input = input("Enter desired password:")
print
```

Comment: What is this `i.isupper()` that you're calling.  What is `i`?

Comment: I am trying to validate an uppercase letter.

Comment: I thought that was the code for calling for an uppercase letter?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: Pythond doesn't have `true/false` but `True/False`

Comment: better don't use in function external variables - like `i` in your functions. Better send it to function as argument.

Comment: you have wrong indentations OR you have empty function `password_check()`

Comment: if you want to check if there is lower letter in password then you should use `for`-loop and check every char separatelly. And if you find letter then return True. And `False` return only after `for`-loop.

Comment: you defined many functions `..._test` but you never execute them. `def` is only to define function but later you have to run this function - or maybe you should remove all these lines with `def` - it could have more sense.

Answer (score 0):

First: I don't know if it is good place for your question.
Maybe it would be better to ask on similar portal [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

---

You have many mistakes.

It has to be `True/False` instead of `true/false`

You have wrong indentations (if you want functions `_test` inside `password_check()`) or you have empty function `password_check()`.

You defined functions `..._test` but you don't execute them in `password_check()`

You have variable `i` but you never created it - so you should get error message.

You should use `for`-loop to work with every char separatelly -like

```
def uppercase_test(password):
    for char in password:
        if char.isupper():
            return True  # return `True` after finding first upper char
    
    return False  # return `False` after checking all chars
```

I don't know how you want to encrypt password so I skip this part.

```
# password should contain at least 8 characters  # PEP8: one space after `#`
def length_test(password):
    #if len(password) >= 8:
    #    return True
    #else:
    #    return False

    # shorter because `>=` gives `True` or `False`
    
    return (len(password) >= 8)

# validating uppercase letter in password  # PEP8: one space after `#`
def uppercase_test(password):
    for char in password:
        if char.isupper():
            return True
    
    return False

# validating lowercase letters in password  # PEP8: one space after `#`
def lowercase_test(password):
    for char in password:
        if char.islower():
            return True

    return False

# validating number in password  # PEP8: one space after `#`
def digit_test(password):
    for char in password:
        if char.isdigit():
            return True

    return False

# validating special character in password  # PEP8: one space after `#`
def special_character_test(password):
    for char in password:
        if char in ("$", "@", "#", "%", "*"):
            return True

    return False

# ----------------------------

def password_check(password):

    if not length_test(password):
        return False

    if not uppercase_test(password):
        return False

    if not lowercase_test(password):
        return False

    if not digit_test(password):
        return False

    if not special_character_test(password):
        return False

    return True

# ----------------------------
    
def encrypt(password):

    # ??? # I have no idea what you want to do

    encrypted_character = + 1
    encrypted_character = - 1
    
# ----------------------------
    
def main ():
    user_input = input("Enter desired password:")
    result = password_check(user_input)
    print('Test result:', result)
    
    if result:  # if result is True:
        encrypt(user_input)
        
# ----------------------------

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```